How to see the difference between two installed versions of a program in Activities Overview?
Now we have flatpaks, snaps and deb versions of a program, they always show up the same in the Activities overview.
E.g. I have a deb version of Inkscape, and I also tried out the Flatpak version.
But they have the same icon and name in the Activities Overview.
Today I stumbled on the problem again trying out the new Flatpak Kodi 21.00 version , while still having the PPA version (now deprecated).
I'm missing a visual marker (a dot, or a subtle background pattern) to show the different versions/sources?
How do I know which version I'm starting? Any solutions/workarounds?

One way would be to select the 9 dot menu at the bottom of the Dock, look for the installed program, right click on its icon and select Show Details - that will indicate which version is installed.
